# How to downgrade the Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, downgrade

I am using Thunderbird 24.2.0 and Ubuntu 13.10.

I want to downgrade to the Thunderbird Version 17.0.11esr.
http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/organizations/all-esr.html

How can I do this?

```
sudo apt-get install thunderbird=17.0.11esr didn't work.
```

Thank you for your answer!!!

Comment: There are no Mozilla ESR packages in Ubuntu, but you can download it from it's site http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/organizations/all-esr.html

Comment: How can I install this file?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get remove thunderbird
sudo apt-get update
sudo-apt-get install thunderbird=17.0.11 (OR thunderbird=17.0.11ers)
```

Not sure if it would work.

Comment: There are no Mozilla ESR packages in Ubuntu